# How to import excel with headers and multiple lines using java spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to import excel with headers and multiple lines using java spring boot,

**Sample file that I have to import is,**
[Sample file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHr6e.png)

I want to import the above given sample file using java spring boot.

**My Sample json,**

```
{
  "ctc": "900000",
  "effectiveFromDate": "2023-04-01",
  "effectiveToDate": "2024-03-31",
  "employee": {
    "employeeId": 1215
  },
  "lines": [
    {
      "element": {
        "elementId": 1
      },
      "elementPercentage": "40"
    },
    {
      "element": {
        "elementId": 2
      },
      "elementPercentage": "55"
    },
    {
      "element": {
        "elementId": "3"
      },
      "elementPercentage": "15"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For importing xlsx files you can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). Then with it you can simply parse rows and map it on your DTO by [getting content](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) of the cells

Example of DTO:

```
public class EmployeeDetails {

    private String ctc;
    private LocalDate effectiveFromDate;
    private LocalDate effectiveToDate;
    private Employee employee;
    private List<LineElement> lines;
}
```